# Two Gaussian Distributions: Independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

A continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597655/finding-the-pdf-of-mathbbc-mathbba-mathbbb)

"Suppose there are two independent random variables: $\mathbb{A}$ ~$\mathit{N}(0,1)$ [ie standard normal] and $\mathbb{B}$ that is ~Bernoulli with $P(\mathbb{B} = 1) = P(\mathbb{B} = -1) = 0.5$."

From the answer: $\mathbb{C}$ ~$\mathit{N}(0,1)$ where $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{AB}$

So, now is there a simple way to check the following for $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

**Independence:**
$$f_{\mathbb{AC}}(a,c) = f_{\mathbb{A}}(a)f_{\mathbb{C}}(c)$$

**Uncorrelated:**
$$\text{E}[\mathbb{AC}] = \text{E}[\mathbb{A}]\text{E}[\mathbb{C}]$$

In order to find $f_{\mathbb{AC}}(a,c)$ do you have to apply Bayes' Rule  and first find the conditional? Or is there a trick since $\mathbb{A}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are Gaussian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're uncorrelated as $\Bbb{AC}=\Bbb{A}^2\Bbb{B},\,\Bbb A$ each have zero mean, but they're not independent since each value of $\Bbb A$ is consistent with a different pair of values of $\Bbb C$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent#A_symmetric_example) has discussed this.